# Conceptually, what's the ideal way to develop detour maps for a large number of nodes

Tags: geoprocessing, vector, routing, network, transportation

I have a road layer of roughly 30,000 links. On these links, I have a total of 15,000 nodes that are sorted in a point layer.

I'm trying to build a detour distance and routing around each asset in case that asset fails.

I have access to ArcGIS (not with network analyst) and QGIS latest build. I have access to PostGIS and pgRouting but I'd rather stay perhaps in network tools whether it's ArcPy, QGIS python or even straight python with shapely and netowkrX

Currently, I'm in the solution design stage. I'm curious as to how you'd recommend I build a "rerouting" engine that can efficiently output `detour_distance` and `list_of_routes_of_detour`

**How would you recommend I build such a system?**

Comment: And the detour is defined as having to get from one side of the failed asset to exactly the other side? I.e. maximum detour.

Comment: @UffeKousgaard Exactly that

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, I would close the link with failed asset and then route between the nodes at each end of the link. Finally: detour_distance = route_distance + length_of_closed_link.